# Linux - 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name(See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

Tags: linux, sendmail, php

I am trying to send an email via Linux server but i never receive it. I'm currently using putty and I use

```
# php -r 'mail("*****@gmail.com","Test subject", "Test Message","From: *****@gmail.com");'
```

Then i go check my message with

```
cat /var/spool/mail/
```

and i got this

```
 ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
   <****@gmail.com>
   **(reason: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1))**

----- Transcript of session follows -----
  ... while talking to domain.ca.:
  >>> MAIL From:<*****@****> SIZE=568
  <<< **550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)**
  554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

I searched on the web and i can't find an answer 
some people say its an authentification problem but they are talking mainly about outlook.
I don't know if it help, but when I do telnet and ehlo i got this

```
# telnet localhost 25
   Trying ::1...
   telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to localhost.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   220 *** ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Fri, 27 Sep 2013 14:47:10 -0400

# ehlo localhost
   250-****Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
   250-PIPELINING   
   250-8BITMIME
   250-SIZE
   250-DSN
   250-ETRN
   250-DELIVERBY
   250 HELP
```

I think it's missing

```
   250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
   250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
```

I don't know if it's because of that i have my error and that i can't send an email? If yes, I don't know what to do to make this apear.

Can someone help me please? I'm new with linux and php mail

Comment: your mail server is trying to pretend it's (say) `example.com`, but is seen by the receiving end as `foo.bar` or whatever instead.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is foo.bar? And how can I change it?

Comment: Your server needs to have [matching forward and reverse DNS records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS), and your mailer needs to put the server name in the HELO/EHLO message. Otherwise many receiving servers assume that your server is spoofing someone else's hostname and probably sending spam.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a VPS or a Dedicated Server try changing the hostname to something resolvable like server@mydomain.com with valid A records for the same

I found the following website useful

[How to fix Invalid HELO Name error](http://blog.topikos.in/2016/05/28/how-to-fix-invalid-helo-name/)